# Need to run the EB.BARCODE function from another application

Tags: browser, barcode-scanner, enterprise

We need to run the EB.barcode function from another application. To test this, we built the tutorial provided by Zebra, barcode.html, which references ebapi-modules.js. We put this in a folder called ZebraScanner – just those two files.

When this folder is placed in the /Android/data/com.symbol.enterprisebrowser folder – and the Config.xml file is modified to set barcode.html as the start page – it works perfectly.

When this folder is placed in the /Download folder .. this popup appears:

```
{"method":"getDefaultID","params":
[],"_rhoClass":"Rho.Barcode","_rhoID
":"0","jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1}

_rhoNativeApiCall:prompt
```

Comment: Code section formatted.

Answer (score 0):

You can only run the EB.Barcode function from within Zebra's Enterprise Browser.  The webview exposed by that product exposes several `addJavaScriptInterface` calls that are required to execute the logic in `ebapi-modules.js`, hence why you are seeing that error.  If you are trying to scan from within another browser such as Chrome or FireFox then a good approach is to use DataWedge with KeyPress & there is an article explaining how to do that at https://developer.zebra.com/blog/listening-keypress-events-datawedge

Comment: Darryn, the entire goal here is to control the scanner from our Android application.   I need to be able to turn the scanner off when an error is presented, and add a short delay after each good scan, so I dont overload the software.   Is this possible?

Comment: From a native Android app?  You mentioned EB so I assumed you were developing a web app.  You have full control of the scanner through DataWedge, I have a getting started tutorial for that: https://medium.com/@darryncampbell_83863/getting-started-with-datawedge-on-zebra-devices-9af2cdd1110c you can turn the scanner off via the DataWedge API in a similar way to how the tutorial uses the API to mimic the hardware trigger.